# Updating textarea with selected item from dropdown in a template using knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvvm, knockout.js

I'm using a knockout template while iterating through a list of cart objects.  In the template I populate a dropdown with all of the products using the Name as the option text and option value.  I want a corresponding text area to populate with the product description which is a property on the object that the dropdown list is bound to.  Is there a knockout way of doing this or do I need to use jQuery?
Thanks for the help.

```
<script type="text/html" id="edit-template">
    <div class="row edit">
        <div class="span3">
            <select data-bind=" options: $root.products, optionsText: 'Name', optionsValue: 'Name', value: Name, optionsCaption: 'Select a Product'"></select>
        </div>
        <div class="span4">
            <!-- This is where I'm not sure what I need to do for this text area -->
            <textarea class="span4" rows="3" data-bind="value: Description"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="span1">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-top:20px;" data-bind="click: $root.save">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**UPDATE**
Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dmase05/trr5e/1/).
In this case I'd like to see the textbox updated with the name and the text area updated with the description.
So full disclosure, my app actually has nothing to do with a shopping cart, but I tried to 
simplify this SO question to a shopping cart example so that readers don't have to understand business domain knowledge of the app.

**UPDATE 2**
Made minor change to the fiddle

Comment: It would be helpful if you could include your model.  Any chance you could create a fiddle?  I think what you're trying to do it easily achievable.

Comment: The `$root` sounds a bit unusual here. I would expect a `$data`. How do you use the template? fiddle would definitely help.

Comment: Sure, I updated the question with the fiddle.  Also, as @Andreas points out, the `$root` usage probably does look suspsect, but the actual app is a little more complex and I have to deal with the view model as is.  I already tried to refactor it and was told to put it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick: http://jsfiddle.net/trr5e/3/

Make sure you have a `ko.observable` which can hold the selected item and connect that to the select element:

```
<select data-bind="options: $root.products, optionsText: 'Name', value: selectedProduct, optionsCaption: 'Select a Product'"></select>
```

Than you can use the properties of the selected item in other controls:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: selectedProduct() ? selectedProduct().Name : ''"/>
```

Comment: Thanks @mhu, this worked well.  +1 for a solution that was easy to adapt to my real scenario and not just the example fiddle.